# How to target list items to specific users/groups?

Tags: list, audience-targeting

Can you explain list audience targeting to me?

I created a list. Went to List Settings, and then to `Audience targeting settings`. I enabled audience targeting. New field `Target Audiences` was added.

I went to Site Settings, then Site permissions and created a group called `Group 1`. Then came back to the list, added new item, and in Target Audience I entered `Group 1`.

User called `User 1` is not member of `Group 1`. I logged in as `User 1` and navigated to list. The item is visible to `User 1`.

I expected, that when item is targeted only to one group, users that are not members, will not be able to see them. What do I have to change? Anything in list permissions or groups?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An audience just allows for promotion to those members, its not meant to be a security tool. For instance, you may put a web part on a page with an audience of Group1. So that when Group2 login in they don't see the WP but Group1 do.

Think of it as a way to classfiy data and surface information to the correct user groups.

Visibility of items is controlled with permissions.